# What is (a reasonable conjectured lower bound on) the query complexity of solving an $n\times n$ system of linear equations given space $O(n)$?

Tags: lower-bounds, space-bounded, query-complexity, linear-equations

I am faced with the following problem:

- A uniformly random $n \times n$ matrix $M$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ is sampled. The algorithm has oracle access to the matrix entries, and each query to an entry "costs 1".
- The algorithm has space $C\cdot n$, where $C > 1$ is some universal constant. It can run in unbounded time on its $C\cdot n$-size worktape (*i.e.* we only count its query complexity).
- The algorithm receives $y = M\cdot x$ where $x$ is a uniformly random vector over $\mathbb{F}$. Its goal is to output $x$.

**My question is:** what is a *reasonable conjecture* about (a lower bound on) the query complexity of this algorithm?

A few notes about what I know (I tried to do my homework before asking the question):

Matrix multiplication being in $\mathsf{DSPACE}(\log^2n)$, there is definitely a polytime-query algorithm for solving a random system of equations in space $C\cdot n$, and it is probably quite easy to find one. I'm however more interested in bounding below the number of queries. I assume any unconditional bound would be way too strong to hope for, but I would be perfectly fine with a *reasonable conjecture* given our current state of knowledge. I also know of Grigoriev's lower bound method, which can be used to show that, in some restricted model of straight-line computation, we have the relation $S\cdot T = \Omega(n^3)$ (I read about it [here](https://cs.brown.edu/people/jsavage/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation_Chapter10.pdf)). However, (1) this is for a very restricted model, and (2) I would expect a significantly better lower bound to hold: especially, in my setting, it only shows that you need $T = \Omega(n^2)$ time, which, well, is obvious.

I would be happy with any partial answer, pointers to the literature, or educated guess of people who worked in related areas and have an intuition about this kind of problem (*i.e.* I don't necessarily need that the conjecture is related to anything well-established, as long as one can explain why it makes sense in light of what we currently know). I'm fine with any choice of finite field (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_2$, or large fields, if any particular choice helps).

Extensions: I'm also interested in the related question where the goal is to output the inner product $\langle z, x\rangle$, where $z$ is also a random vector given as input to the algorithm. I am further also interested in the setting where the space is $n^{1+\varepsilon}$, for any $\varepsilon < 1$.

=== EDIT ===

As Clément C. correctly pointed out in the comments, Ran Raz's celebrated [time-space lower bounds on parity learning](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3186563) is strongly related to my question. And indeed, it is the starting point of my question. So, it might be helpful here that I clarify the distinction between what Raz proved and what I want:

- Raz's paper shows that if you have $< n^2/20$ memory and receive a stream $(m_i, \langle m_i, x \rangle)$ where $x$ is a secret vector and the $m_i$ are the rows of a random matrix $M$, you need exponentially many samples to recover $x$.
- This is neat, but this is for single-pass streaming: what happens if you can make *two passes* on the data? Well, Garg, Raz, and Tal have a very nice [follow-up](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10121212) showing that with less than $\Omega(n^{1.5})$ space, you would need $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ samples to recover $x$. Notice how the bound degrades quickly!
- As of today, nothing is known for 3 passes or more.

Now, in my question, the adversary is considerably more powerful: he is given *arbitrary oracle access* to the matrix $M$ (which is now limited to $n$ samples for simplicity). So, the adversary can make an arbitrary number of passes on $M$, query it in the order that they want, etc. In this regime, one cannot hope for a bound *a la* Ran Raz: it should actually be feasible to recover $x$ with polynomially-many passes on $M$ even with $C\cdot n$ space (because matrix-vector multiplication is in $\mathsf{DSPACE}(\mathsf{polylog}(n))$. Hence, the tradeoff must inherently be different. Furthermore, in light of the current limits of the techniques in this line of work, I don't expect any of it to magically generalize to "arbitrary oracle access to the matrix": handling two passes is already hard, and three passes is open... So, instead, I'm just hoping for a reasonable conjecture on what an expert would estimate to be likely true, a "rule of thumb" if you like, of the form "we expect any such adversary to require at least $n^d$ accesses to $M$", with some constant $d> 2$. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: I think you'd have to query all the entries. By linearity, if you change any one entry of M, unless the corresponding entry of x happens to be 0, you'd change the output.

Comment: Of course! But I'm actually wondering whether you have to query *more* than all entries: because of the $C\cdot n$ space restriction, you cannot just "download the full matrix", so it's very likely that, to compute the solution $x$, you will have to re-query some entries many times. My hope is actually that a number of queries significantly larger than $n^2$ is required given this space restriction.

Comment: A related result is that the Borodin-Cook method gives an $ST=\Omega(n^4)$ lower bound for matrix inversion (it's also in the John Savage book you linked). That should imply a worst-case $ST=\Omega(n^3)$ lower bound for your problem in the branching program model.

Comment: Interesting! This is stronger than what I knew, but unfortunately in the $S \approx n$ regime, it still only gives $T = \Omega(n^2)$, which as Joshua observed should be relatively straightforward. My hope is that a larger polynomial gap can be reasonably conjectured, even if we don't have a provable time-space tradeoff.

Comment: This seems relevant? https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3186563

Comment: This paper was actually my starting point, so it's indeed relevant, but it does not solve my problem! I'm editing the question to clarify this point. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the expected role of $M$ and $x$ being sampled uniformly at random? Do you want an average-case lower bound?

Comment: Yes, ideally I would want that (the same way that Raz's lower bound is average case). But a worst case (conjectured) lower bound would be an excellent starting point (hopefully together with some intuition about what could be a candidate hard distribution for M and x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, a pretty good answer to my question was already given in [Wiedemann's seminal paper on solving sparse linear systems](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/profs/informatique/Francois.Morain/Master1/Crypto/projects/Wiedemann86.pdf). I am actually quite familiar with the paper, but I had totally missed the connection!

Wiedemann's result is commonly described as an algorithm to solve $w$-sparse linear systems in time $O(w\cdot n + n^2)$. But in fact, it does much more than that. A good abstraction of Wiedemann's result is that it gives an algorithm solving linear systems in the black-box model of linear algebra. Concretely, given a singular matrix $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{F}^n$, Wiedemann gives an algorithm that finds a solution $x$ to $Ax = b$ using

- $\tilde{O}(n^2)$ arithmetic operations (either over $\mathbb{F}$ if the field is large enough, else over an extension field),
- $O(n)$ space, and
- $O(n)$ calls to a *black-box for $A$* which, on input a vector $z$, outputs $Az$.

I learned about the formalism of black-box linear algebra (where access to the matrix is given via a black-box for computing matrix-vector product) in the works of Eberly, see e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04514) (I don't know whether it originated in his work, though). That Wiedemann's algorithm runs in linear space can be extracted from the algorithm; I did not find it stated explicitly in his work, but it is mentioned explicitly e.g. [here](https://www.dima.unige.it/%7Emorafe/MaterialeCTC/KaSa91.pdf).

Now, in my model, $A$ is singular with very high probability (assuming $\mathbb{F}$ is large enough), and a *call to the black-box* can easily be emulated using $O(n)$ space and $n^2$ oracle queries to the matrix. Overall, this yields an $O(n^3)$-query, $O(n^3)$-work, $O(n)$-space algorithm for solving linear systems in the model of my question.

I find this extremely interesting. I had never observed that Wiedemann's algorithm implies that one can *match* the efficiency of Gaussian elimination using only $O(n)$ local space, and I've never seen this observation elsewhere, but it looks like a pretty neat result for general matrices (in contrast, Wiedemann's result is almost always described as a way to save *time* when solving linear systems with *structured* matrices). This $O(n^3)$ is also much smaller than what I would have been initially tempted to conjecture.

Because my original question asks for a conjecture, let me put forth the following conjecture:

- (weak version) In the black-box model of linear algebra with linear space, Wiedemann's algorithm is essentially optimal in terms of calls to the black-box (i.e., there is no $O(n)$ space algorithm making $n^{1-\varepsilon}$ calls to the black-box)
- (strong version) In the oracle model of my question (with linear space), Wiedemann's algorithm is essentially optimal in terms of queries to the matrix (i.e., there is no $O(n)$ space algorithm making $n^{3-\varepsilon}$ calls to the black-box)

These conjectures seem sensible to me, since approaching the matrix multiplication time for solving linear systems while using linear space would sound like a huge breakthrough. Of course, they are nothing more than (vaguely educated) conjectures, but I though it'd be interesting to share them here!

Comment: An $O(n^3)$-time, $\tilde{O}(n)$-space algorithm based on LDL decomposition is also described in the John Savage book (Theorem 6.5.4), and it actually computes the entire matrix inverse (for which the Borodin-Cook bound is tight).

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I actually don't have the book, I only read the pdf of chapter 10 (about space time tradeoffs). I will look it up!